# Online C++ compiler: output binary files for me?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, executable

Is there any website which would allow me to upload my source code, and it would return me the binary files which can be ran from Linux ?

I am so bad at using Linux, that this kind of service would be a life saver for me.

I know codepad.org but as far as I know, it only outputs the text from those programs. I need to download the executables which it generates while compiling.

Comment: You'd do yourself a big favor if you just learned how to compile...

Comment: For a small fee of 20 USD, just e-mail your code to me.

Comment: Writing the source code can be difficult, since you are writing that, but using the compiler should be much more easy. Pl. use the command g++ yourfilename -o outputfile to compile and make an executable

Comment: I wouldn't trust the binary coming out from such a site. That would be a really good way to catch a virus.

Comment: @EmilVikström, i dont understand how that can be less trusted than for example stackoverflow.com ? Any website could be hacked and injected with viruses. How can you download any executable, do you just execute them with trust always? But if someone else compiles it from your code, it magically becomes less trusted? I dont get the idea behind that paranoia.

Comment: I think the author of this question had the same problem as me. I need a friend's binary executable (without sharing the actual code) but his executable does not work in my laptop since mine is Mac and his is Linux.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know of any site like that (nor would I necessarily trust what it might return to me).

Any reason you can't just compile your own source code? Any programmer should know how to compile the source code they write. Designing/writing code is hard, compiling is simple (and easier than uploading/downloading files :)

Assuming your C++ source is saved with a `.cpp` extension, just do:

```
   g++ yourprog.cpp
```

and it will generate a binary executable with the default name `a.out` which can be executed by simply typing

```
   ./a.out
```

at the prompt.

If you wanted to enable all warnings (a good idea) you'd add the `-Wall` command line switch. To name the excutable use the `-o` (for output) switch. Here is an example of compiling a program with both of these:

```
   g++ -Wall yourprog.cpp -o prog
```

This compiles source code, `yourprog.ccp`, with full warning messages enabled, and generates an executable named `prog` (you can choose any name). Execute it the same way as the previous executable at the prompt:   `./prog`

If you use the `.C` extension, simply substitute `.C` for `.cpp` above.

Here are [more examples](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_54.html) of compiling C++ programs and here a [tutorial](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html). Finally the [gcc/g++ man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/g++-4.0/)

Please note, as pointed out by a helpful comment from @MagnusHoff that you may have to install the compiler and associated tools in case you don't already have them available. @MagnusHoff gives instructions for Ubuntu in his comment below, your specifics may vary depending on what distribution you are working with.

Comment: Good job ignoring the question xD this will be more useful.

Comment: It's worth noting that the compiler and related tools will need to be installed. On Ubuntu this is done by installing the `build-essential` package, for example with this command line: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: @MagnusHoff Excellent point, I'll add a note about this to the answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How probable it is that if i compile it on ubuntu, it will not work on some other linux version? if i just use basic libraries?

Comment: @Rookie Moving binaries is always a bit "iffy", still it is done (after all, that's how, for instance, Microsoft and most commercial software houses distribute their wares). Binaries are closely tied to the underlying hardware (and of course any external libraries if they aren't statically linked). If you are going from the same type of machine to another, and aren't using anything "odd" in terms of libraries, chances are it will work, though to be sure you ought to try. Best to share the source if you can though (if that's possible).

Comment: This is all very well and good until you find yourself needing to upgrade your OS to upgrade to the latest GCC to access a particular feature (in, say, C++11). Sometimes, the best, most straightforward approach (such as the one outlined in your answer) is the hardest, *sigh* :-) (And yes, yes, I can compile GCC from source, but it's probably faster to reinstall the OS in my case.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use codeblocks which is available in the Ubuntu software center (it's free and i think you can find versions for other distributions too).
http://www.codeblocks.org/
 I think the interface is easy to get used to. Good luck!

Comment: I would add KDevelop or QtCreator to the recommended list.

Comment: So i dont need to install VirtualBox, just the codeblocks!? thats awesome.

Comment: Indeed! It is a standalone program and it works after a few clicks.

Comment: where do i select the platform it will compile the binary file? so far it just makes exes for windows...

Comment: i googled everywhere and couldnt find a thing saying i can compile to linux from windows with codeblocks... are you sure it does that?

Comment: Yes, i don't use it, but a very good friend of mine is using ubuntu as main OS and uses codeblocks for compiling. I think you don't have to make it a console project. I'm not very sure though.

Comment: i mean, if i compile from windows, it can compile it as linux executable? or do i have to use linux to compile for linux, and windows for compiling for windows?

Comment: Each OS with it's own compile. Windows for windows and Linux for Linux.